# Prevent all images from being dragable except predefined images (HTML 5)

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

All images are `draggable="true"` by default.

How can I prevent all images (**and also user selected segments**) in a page to be dragable, except few images.

I'm looking for a dynamically code in `JS` and not `HTML` code (by `addEvent()` function).

For example Here:  http://html5demos.com/drag you can drag and drop the HTML5 logo inside the trash image, case that was not supposed to happen.

Comment: Have you tried `draggable="false"`?

Comment: It is working, but the problem is not just images, the user can select some text in my page and then drag it into a drop-able area.
How can I prevent dragging things in my page in generally ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Prevent the `dragstart` event](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/q9yT2/):

```
document.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

The usual cross browser event attaching provisos apply.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems to be the correct way to do it, but now I can't drag some images that I wanted to drag in first place.
Is it possible to check in this function the ID of the Object ?

Comment: @Guy Then attach the event listener to the images you don't want to drag or the areas of the page you don't want items dragged from, or write a `dragstart` function which checks what the object is before deciding whether or not to allow or deny dragging.

Comment: How can I check the type of the object from `e`?